# Can a plugIn in QGIS let me cut polylines where the points of another shapefile are?

Tags: point, line, splitting

I want to know if there is a plugin/tool in QGIS, that let me cut lines of a shapefile where the points of another shapefile are.

Comment: There are many duplicates to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the clip tool, in the vector tool bar,

or you can install this plugin : [click =)](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html)